# How did Norman and Emma not get seen?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

So, I just watched episode 1 of the Promised Neverland. Looks like a lot of potential.

**Question:** How did Norman and Emma possibly not get seen as they left the gated area?

You can clearly see, by the position of the characters at timestamp 18:43 in episode 1, that this should have been impossible.

I am trying to watch this and this is minor but I hope it is just a mistake on the animation side and not some sign towards a lack of attention to detail of this manga.

Comment: I don't think it's explained anywhere, but I guess you could say they could escape because it was dark and that they went unnoticed while the demons were focusing their attention under the truck, or not alert even.